# Hibernate 6 - IdentifierGenerator - Delegating to default generator for NULL IDs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a specific requirement to set and save an ID of an entity manually, based on a mapping table from a legacy system. I created a class that achieved this functionality before an upgrade to Hibernate 6.

The basis of the class is to use the ID that has been passed (i.e. non-null) or "let" Hibernate use its default mechanism for generating values.

I had a working version of this code suitable for Hibernate < 6, now that an upgrade is necessary, the code below no longer is suitable.

```java
@Slf4j
public class CustomIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator
{

    @Override
    public Serializable generate( final SharedSessionContractImplementor session, final Object obj )
    {

        Serializable id = session.getEntityPersister( null, obj ).getClassMetadata().getIdentifier( obj, session );
        if ( id == null || Long.parseLong( id.toString() ) <= 0 )
        {
            // If the ID is not set or is less than or equal to 0, let Hibernate generate it.
            log.debug( "Hibernate will generate a new ID for entity [{}]", obj.getClass().getName() );
            id = super.generate( session, obj ); // Cannot do this anymore!
        }
        else
        {
            log.debug( "Using provided ID [{}] for entity [{}]", id, obj.getClass().getName() );
        }

        return id;
    }
    
}
```

And its usage

```java
@GenericGenerator( name = "CustomIdGenerator",
                   type = domain.util.CustomIdGenerator.class )
public class Tournament
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "CustomIdGenerator" )
    private Long id;
}
```

Any ideas on how to adapt this code to work with Hibernate 6?

Comment: I have written an answer that may help you to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess as a fix you could do something like next one approach because you have session.

```
@Slf4j
public class CustomIdentifierGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

  @Override
  public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object obj) {

    Serializable id = session.getEntityPersister( null, obj ).getClassMetadata().getIdentifier( obj, session );
    if (id == null || Long.parseLong(id.toString()) <= 0) {
      // If the ID is not set or is less than or equal to 0, let Hibernate generate it.
      log.debug("Hibernate will generate a new ID for entity [{}]", obj.getClass().getName());

      String sqlQuery = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM Tournament";
      Optional<Long> query = session.createQuery(sqlQuery, Long.class).getResultStream().findFirst();
      id = query.get() +  1;

    } else {
      log.debug("Using provided ID [{}] for entity [{}]", id, obj.getClass().getName());
    }

    return id;
  }
}
```

Or to use `session.createNativeQuery()` and extract next value of sequence.